Creating Loop for Triangles
I have multiple objects that I created which include data I need for each triangle. I now want to create triangles and export to csv, but I have so many datasets that I'd like to do this in a loop. Bonus points if I can also name each csv the same as the triangle name (for example below, LiabilityTriangleMonthly). My current code that works on a one-by-one basis is as follows:
install.packages("ChainLadder")
install.packages("writexl")
install.packages("openxlsx")
install.packages("data.table")
install.packages("xlsx")
install.packages("sqldf")
library(ChainLadder)
library(writexl)
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(sqldf)
LiabilityData_Monthly<-read.csv.sql("//filepath/FullTriangle.csv" , sql = "select * from file where LineofBusiness=194")

    Liability_Triangle_Monthly = as.triangle(LiabilityData_Monthly, 
                              dev = "MaturityMonth", 
                              origin = "AY", 
                              value = "IncurredTotal")

    LiabilityTriangleMonthly=as.matrix(Liability_Triangle_Monthly)
    LiabilityTriangleMonthly[is.na(LiabilityTriangleMonthly)]<-0
    write.csv(LiabilityTriangleMonthly,"//filepath/LiabilityTriangleMonthly.csv")



For reference, the names of 2 of my objects:
LiabilityData_Monthly
PhysDamData_Monthly
Below is my sample dataset (FullTriangle.csv) that I'm pulling my data from:



AY
MaturityMonth
IncurredTotal
LineOfBusiness




2023
3
1000
194


2023
6
5000
194


2023
9
10000
194


2023
12
15000
194


2023
15
20000
194


2024
3
100
194


2023
3
100
212


2023
6
500
212


2023
9
1000
212


2023
12
1500
212


2023
15
2000
212


2024
3
150
212


2023
3
1500
193


2023
6
4000
193


2023
9
9000
193


2023
12
12000
193


2023
15
16000
193


2024
3
200
193



Tried to create a list to loop through... but very new to R and need a simpler version than what I've seen on this site already.

You will need to provide some sample data.

Also kindly define the needed packages. Where is as.triangle from? Try to make your example minimal and self-contained.

Assuming you need to run subsets across the LineOfBusiness column, consider defining a method to run one split, then iteratively call the method passing subset splits using by (object-oriented wrapper to tapply). Also, to properly name CSVs, below builds a small lookup data frame to merge to main data frame:
# HANDLE DATA SETS
FullTriangle <- read.csv("//filepath/FullTriangle.csv")

LineCodes <- data.frame(
  LineOfBusiness = c(193, 194, 212),
  LineOfBusinessTitle = c("Other_Monthly", "LiabilityData_Monthly", "PhysDamData_Monthly")
)

FullTriangle <- merge(FullTriangle. LineCodes, by="LineOfBusiness")

# USER-DEFINED METHOD
proc_triangle <- function(sub) {
    tri = as.triangle(
        sub, 
        dev = "MaturityMonth", 
        origin = "AY", 
        value = "IncurredTotal"
    )

    tri <- as.matrix(tri)
    tri[is.na(tri)] <- 0
    write.csv(tri, paste0("//filepath/", tri$LineOfBusinessTitle[1], ".csv"))

    return(tri)
}

# BUILD NAMED LIST OF TRIANGLE WITH CSV OUTPUTS
df_list <- by(FullTriangle, FullTriangle$LineOfBusiness, proc_triangle)

